# Reporting on XML nodes in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, api, foreach

I'd be wanting to iterate through a set of XML and then pass those to variables which can be printed.

Here is an example of the data:

```xml
<applications>
 <size>75</size>
 <application>
    <name>Applications 1</name>
    <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 1</path>
    <version>10.14</version>
 </application>
 <application>
    <name>Application 2</name>
    <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 2</path>
    <version>6.3.9</version>
 </application>
</applications>
```

I've looked at using `ForEach-Object` when trying to output it but to no avail.

```bsh
[string]$applicationProperties = $API.applications.application | ForEach-Object {
   $_.name
   $_.path
   $_.version
}
```

This works but puts them all on one line, I'd like them so they print on individual lines but I couldn't prefix the `$_` variable.

e.g. so I'd like to have name/path/version data saved to variables

```bsh
[string]$applicationProperties = $API.applications.application | ForEach-Object {
   [string]$name_var = $_.name 
   [string]$path_var = $_.path
   [string]$version_var = $_.variable
}
```

This gives me one "application", but not all the possible objects. Also mentions that even when I'm putting down `$name_var` it's not accessing that variable? Do I need to do something to access that variable?

---

Created this `$applicationProperties = "Application Name $($applicationProperties[0].name)"`

but when calling `$applicationProperties` I get `Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.`

Comment: `[string]$applicationProperties` -> `[string[]]$applicationProperties`

Comment: Personally I'd avoid strict typing in PowerShell scripts unless there is a good reason to enforce types.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers good to know, is there a solution you'd recommend?

Comment: I thought I just did.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers so once I've made that change, how would I access those variables? I'm new to PowerShell so sorry for the questions.

Comment: Why don't you just print $API.applications.application? this has the name path and version already in a table format? just type $API.applications.application in the console and you will have your results.

Comment: @SysEngineer The idea is to export all the properties out into a text file for another application - they will need to be formatted as "Name = $Name_Var", and this would need to be done for each application listed.

Comment: @andyarnold okay so like this
Name = Application1
Path = /path/
Version = 10.14
Name = Application2
Path = /path/
Version = 6.3.9

Right? All on new lines?

Comment: @SysEngineer perfect, that's the idea.

Comment: Please do not add tags to the subject of your question, or a solution to the question body. Accepting an answer is sufficient for marking a question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectNodes()` with an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) expression instead of dot-access, then output the name and inner text of each selected node:

```
$API.SelectNodes('//application/*') | ForEach-Object {
    '{0}={1}' -f $_.Name, $_.InnerText
} | Set-Content 'output.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I set this to variables? As when tried to use this I got `= hash literal errors` I've got it exporting to the output.txt file great.

Comment: What do you mean "set this to variables"? What do you want in variables, and what do you want to do with those variables?

Comment: I'd want to output them into the files I'm exporting. There are hundreds of fields I'm also exporting, so having another file wouldn't do the job - hence why having the data in variables makes exporting them easier. *edit but that's just my 2 cents, you know better so I'll take your advice.

Comment: What fields to what files? We cannot help you unless you're more specific about what data you have, and what you want to do with it exactly.

Comment: The other fields are irrelevant, I just want to have it so I have `Name = $name` for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this out.

```
[xml]$API = 
@"
<applications>
 <size>75</size>
 <application>
    <name>Applications 1</name>
    <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 1</path>
    <version>10.14</version>
 </application>
 <application>
    <name>Application 2</name>
    <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 2</path>
    <version>6.3.9</version>
 </application>
</applications>
"@

$applicationProperties = $API.applications.application | ForEach-Object {
@"
Name = $($_.name)
Path = $($_.path)
Version = $($_.version)
"@   
}

$applicationProperties | Out-File -FilePath C:\Output\appProps.txt
```

*EDIT*

```
[xml]$API = 
@"
<applications>
 <size>75</size>
 <application>
    <name>Applications 1</name>
    <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 1</path>
    <version>10.14</version>
 </application>
 <application>
    <name>Application 2</name>
    <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 2</path>
    <version>6.3.9</version>
 </application>
</applications>
"@

$applicationProperties = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

$API.applications.application | ForEach-Object {
    $myObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'Name'    = $_.Name
        'Path'    = $_.Path
        'Version' = $_.Version
    }
    #Adding objects to an array list prints the index each insert. Use null to suppress.
    $null = $applicationProperties.Add($myObj)
}
```

To access the variables type $applicationProperties in the console and press enter. It will print each object in that array. To access an object at a specific index (arrays start at 0) $applicationProperties[0] for the first item $applicationProperties[1] for the second and so forth.

Comment: that would be great, but I've got lots of other properties and fields which I'm including too, is there some way to do it by doing ForEach-Object and exporting them to variables which are usable?

Comment: @andyarnold could you give me full example data on what it is your are trying to manipulate?

Comment: the actual data source is massive. But what I linked above in the first XML snippet is a small part of the data, I'm just caught up on exporting it to variables, is that something which is possible?

Comment: cool. So if I wanted Name to be a variable I'd do something like: `$nameVar = $applicationProperties[0]` ?

Comment: @andyarnold `$nameVar = $applicationProperties[0].Name` yessir!

Comment: @andyarnold but there is no reason to recreate a new variable when you can already have a variable with access to the value you need. Does that make sense? If I can use `$applicationProperties[0].Name` to get an application name, there is no reason for me to then store that AGAIN in another variable.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, it doesn't seem to be prompting a .Name after the array. I'll need to double check what I've done...

Comment: @andyarnold thats fine it doesn't need to autocomplete and I'm not sure if it normally does. Just type that into the command line and see if it prints out anything!

Comment: Got it working, but only worked for one of the applications, I can't put it into the string section due to `Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal` any advice?

Comment: @andyarnold can you put in your new code in your original post in an **EDIT** section so I can see what you are attempting?

Comment: added to question